# Criar view transformando excluindo ou transformando DATE em VARCHAR no ORACLE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Eu tenho uma tabela com 58 colunas diferentes e gostaria de criar uma *View* que trate os campos *DATE* como *VARCHAR*, sem que eu tenha que discriminar todas as colunas na criação da *View*.

`CREATE VIEW VW_TESTE AS SELECT * FROM TABELA`

Como segue no exemplo:

ID, BIGINT
NOME, VARCHAR
LOGIN, DATE
INSCRICAO, DATE
EMAIL, VARCHAR

E retornasse isso:

ID, BIGINT
NOME, VARCHAR
LOGIN, VARCHAR
INSCRICAO, VARCHAR
EMAIL, VARCHAR

OU

ID, BIGINT
NOME, VARCHAR
EMAIL, VARCHAR

Tentei fazer o comando
"Select * from Tabela where data_type = 'DATE' "

Mas não funcionou.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/261439-resolvido%C2%A0procedure-geradora-de-trigger-de-auditoria/ uma vez fiz esta procedure que gera uma trigger para auditoria a idiea básica poderia ser usada para gerar a view que faria o "to-char" quando o campo fosse date

Comment: Mas confesso não ver motivos para este trabalho

Comment: @Motta neste caso eu não tenho a permissão de DBA no DB Oracle com meu usuário. Usando o `to_char` eu teria que fazer uma _view_  tendo que colocar todas as colunas. Mas isso não é necessariamente um problema agora. No entanto, como estou trabalhando num projeto de bigData, isso pode ser um problema em breve com tabelas ainda mais largas.
No mais, vou analisar o que você mandou e trocar uma ideia com o DBA. O problema é que isso que estou fazendo é apenas para testes.

Comment: Mas qual a razão das datas terem de ser char na view ?

Comment: @Motta desculpe a demora. Então, eu estou fazendo um import para um cluster Hadoop e tá dando um erro estranho com um dataset selecionado. Por isso gostaria de transformar em string, pra evitar o formato date que causa incompatibilidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue exemplo gerando dbms_output , mas uma ideia basica , gera o script

```
DECLARE
  VN_C NUMBER := 0;
  VN_COLUNAS NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO VN_COLUNAS 
  FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'NOMETABELA';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_NOMETABELA AS SELECT ');
  FOR R IN (SELECT (CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'DATE' THEN 'TO_CHAR('  || COLUMN_NAME || ',' || '''DD/MM/YYYY''' || ') ' || COLUMN_NAME 
                         ELSE COLUMN_NAME END) COLUNA
            FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'NOMETABELA')
  LOOP
    VN_C := VN_C + 1;
    IF VN_C < VN_COLUNAS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.COLUNA || ',');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R.COLUNA);
    END IF;  
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FROM NOMETABELA');
END;
```

Pode-se fazer uma procedure gerado de script ou da própria view